# How to handle error scenario in Typeahead search with mergeMap Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Trying to Typeahead search functionality with API data, If we give valid data autosuggestions are coming properly and if we give invalid data, it is giving error message but If we enter again valid data API is not triggering. So I tried to fix and tried below code and help me how to handle error scenario for invalid data.

```
asyncData: string;
dataSource: Observable<any>;

this.dataSource = new Observable((observer) => {
    observer.next(this.asyncData)
}).mergeMap(() => {
    return this.http.get('/api/testAPI',{params: {param1: param1}});
});
```

Comment: "and if we give invalid data, it is giving error message " how do you know its invalid

Comment: Im displaying error message on text box for invalid data and If invalid data API gives this data "{"timestamp":"2020-04-22T07:22:35.004+0000","errorMessage":"No results found","errorCode":404,"errorDetails":"uri=/API/testAPI"}"

Comment: how this.http
    return this.http.get('/api/testAPI',{params: {param1: param1}}); works exactly ? what is this.http return this.http ? something is not ok here

Comment: If I enter some valid data, its giving typeahead list, if we give invalid data like any chars, special chars its giving above error message and I'm displaying in text box like No Data. And again I'm trying to give valid data, this time API is not triggered.

Comment: Sorry, "this.http" is typo,  removed it and here is the original one "return this.http.get('/api/testAPI',{params: {param1: param1}});", I just updated latest code in the question.

Comment: you should try make a stackblitz example out of this since your code looks like it is not suppose to work at all, try to use https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-searchbox-example this example

Comment: and you can start by using switchMap instead of mergeMap which is more suitable for searching box since you need to dispose the last search if new one arrives

Answer (score 0):

The `new Observable()` seems unnecessary. The usage of the HTTP request isn't shown. In any case, what you'd need is some form of error handling. You could use `catchError` operator to convert errors to either valid response or not to emit them.

```js
import { NEVER } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

return this.http.get('/api/testAPI',{params: {param1: param1}}).pipe(
  catchError(() => NEVER)
);
```

This uses RxJS `NEVER` constant that will not emit. Beware if you wish to handle the error in the subscription. This won't emit.

Comment: Hi @Michael D, I Just added  .pipe(catchError(() => NEVER)); still its not working, if we enter invalid data  first and enter valid data API is not triggered.

Comment: @Rajasekhar: Try `pipe(catchError(() => of(null)))`

Comment: Hi @Michael D, If possible could you please help me on this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67549092/how-to-update-the-params-for-every-pagination-button-clicks-in-angular-datatable